# CoreData: keypath name not found in entity

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-data, core-data-migration

I tried to implement lightweight migration in coreData. I already had a project created with core data. First I created a new model version in it, then renamed an attribute from "name" to "name2". Now I changed the current model version to the new version with an attribute renamed as "name2". I changed the renaming identifier in the new model to "name"
[image]

When I run the app I'm getting an error like this
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath name not found in entity '". What did I do wrong?

Comment: What line of code causes this exception? Are you sure it's the migration?

Comment: It just crashes and shows error on appDelegate. After I added an exception break point it stops when i try to perform a fetch operation. Here is a link to my project without the additional model version. "https://github.com/SimeonIrudhayaRaj/NSFetchedResultsControllerTutorial" This where I tried adding a new model version and renamed an attribute.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it crashes due to something related to migration. If i just change the current model version to the old one it works fine.

Comment: - Make sure you also renamed it in your model class using this entity? 
- If you have created core data class of this entity, make sure you re-created it after new modle version.

Comment: where can i find the model class?